# CASE WHEN converting smallint to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched a bit on either using cast or convert but failed to succeed in my query.

This is my query right now:

```
CASE WHEN ENR.GR = '-1' THEN 'TK'
WHEN ENR.GR = '0' THEN 'K'
ELSE ENR.GR
END AS 'Grade'
```

I have tried using case and convert like this:

```
CASE WHEN ENR.GR = '-1' THEN CAST('TK' as varchar(2))
WHEN ENR.GR = '0' THEN CAST('K' as varchar(1))
ELSE ENR.GR
END AS 'Grade'
```

I haven't been able to run it without getting the

```
"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'TK' to data type 
smallint." error.
```

Sorry this has probably been asked multiple times, if someone could explain what I am doing wrong or point me to the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conversation  should go with `ELSE` part :

```
CASE WHEN ENR.GR = '-1' 
     THEN 'TK'
     WHEN ENR.GR = '0' 
     THEN 'K'
     ELSE CAST(ENR.GR AS VARCHAR(255))
END AS 'Grade'
```

You don't need to use single quote with numeric value. Just use :

```
CASE WHEN ENR.GR = -1
     THEN 'TK'
     WHEN ENR.GR = 0
     THEN 'K'
     ELSE CAST(ENR.GR AS VARCHAR(255))
END AS 'Grade'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was simpler than I was expecting. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `gr` column is smallint, you need to cast it to varchar:

```
CASE
    WHEN ENR.GR = -1 THEN 'TK'
    WHEN ENR.GR =  0 THEN 'K'
    ELSE CAST(ENR.GR AS VARCHAR(6))
END AS 'Grade'
```

This is because the `CASE` expression returns exactly one datatype and it attempts to convert result from all `WHEN` and `ELSE` branches to that datatype. The resultant datatype is chosen [based on precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Since smallint has higher priority than varchar, it attempts to convert 'DK' and 'K' to smallint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the smallint to varchar.

```
DECLARE @gr smallint = -1;

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN @gr = '-1' THEN 'TK' ELSE CASE WHEN @gr = '0' THEN 'K' ELSE CAST(@gr AS VARCHAR(10)) END END AS Grade
```